# unable to use foreach to inserts lines of the data frame into oracle table

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to insert a data frame to a oracle table as below:

my data frame looks like this:

dat

```
              DATE         LPAR smt lcpu    mem psize ent PercentUsr PercentSys PercentWait
3 2013-05-06 00:02:00 server1   4   96 393216    64  16       25.3        8.9         8.1
4 2013-05-06 00:02:30 server1   4   96 393216    64  16       23.2        8.3         7.8
5 2013-05-06 00:03:00 server1   4   96 393216    64  16       21.5        8.8         9.1
6 2013-05-06 00:03:30 server1   4   96 393216    64  16       23.2        8.8         8.2
7 2013-05-06 00:04:00 server1   4   96 393216    64  16       22.1        8.7         7.5
8 2013-05-06 00:04:30 server1   4   96 393216    64  16       21.9        9.8         8.4
  PercentIdle Physc PercentEntc Lbusy   App  Vcsw Phint
3        57.8  6.36        39.7  21.5 39.67 19650  1636
4        60.7  5.81        36.3  21.1 39.85 16636  1436
5        60.6  5.68        35.5  20.6 40.35 16291  1349
6        59.8  6.02        37.6  21.2 37.92 20199  1495
7        61.7  5.78        36.1  20.0 40.08 18721  1499
8        60.0  6.00        37.5  20.5 40.59 19810  1443
```

\n

```
library(RCurl) 
library(RODBC)
library(snow)
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)

if(nrow(dat)>1) {
                 tryCatch({
                        ch=odbcConnect("<id>",pwd = "<passwd>")
                        sqlSave(ch,dat, tablename="TEST", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
                        },error = function(e) {
                            print("unable to insert the whole data frame, will try by line, next")
                            ch=odbcConnect("<id>",pwd = "<passwd>")

                                foreach(k=1:nrow(dat)) %dopar% {
                                print(dat[k,])
                                        tryCatch({
                                                sqlSave(ch,dat[k,], tablename="TEST", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
                                                },error=function(e) {
                                                    print("unable to insert, duplicate record")
                                                    print(e)
                                                })
                                }
                            odbcClose(ch)

                        })
                        odbcClose(ch)
            }
```

looks like this part of the code is not being executed, any ideas what I might missing here:

```
},error = function(e) {
                            print("unable to insert the whole data frame, will try by line, next")
                            ch=odbcConnect("<id>",pwd = "<passwd>")

                                foreach(k=1:nrow(dat)) %dopar% {
                                print(dat[k,])
                                        tryCatch({
                                                sqlSave(ch,dat[k,], tablename="TEST", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
                                                },error=function(e) {
                                                    print("unable to insert, duplicate record")
                                                    print(e)
                                                })
                                }
                            odbcClose(ch)
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301870/unable-to-insert-each-line-of-a-data-frame-to-oracle-table-using-r) question? And are you sure that inserting rows into a db is something that will benefit from parallelization? (I'm unconvinced.)

Comment: I need to insert the data frame by line by line for certain situation. In order to speed it up, I am using foreach. It looks like not going into the table. I thought this was working but, not sure why it is not working at this point.

Comment: But why would doing this in parallel speed it up?

Comment: @Joran, there are so many files and need to complete the insertion to the db in a certain time. Do you think my syntax is correct?

Comment: You're not thinking this through. Let's assume for a moment that the db resides on a single physical drive. An insertion would require touching the disk at some point. You can't touch the disk in parallel. The insertions are going to happen one at a time no matter how you split up the requests on your local machine.

Comment: @joran, only other think I can think of of is the use for loop like this: for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){qlSave(ch,dat[i,], tablename="TEST", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)}. can you recommendend any other way?

Comment: If you really have to insert them one at a time (why not check for primary key conflicts in bulk with a single query...?) then a for loop seems like your best option.

Comment: @Joran, that's what I am doing but it seems slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing this `foreach` loop with `doSNOW`, the database connection object `ch` will be auto-exported to the cluster workers, but the resulting object will almost certainly not work.  Objects like file connections can't be serialized and sent to other processes and work correctly.

You could try creating the database connections on each of the workers before executing the `foreach` loop and use `.noexport='ch'` to prevent it from being auto-exported, but I agree with the comments made by @joran that it won't be worth it.